# ComboBox drop down always on top

Tags: c#, winapi, user-controls

I have a User Control with a Janus Combo Box. While dropping down, the dropped down menu will get inside the Group box or Panel (means the Parent Control). I need to make it always on top of all controls.

I tried with BringtoFront() for the Combo Box and UC itself, But I did not get any result.

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: BringToFront, the method or bring to front the designer tool?

Comment: this.BringToFront(); for the UC itsself

Comment: Try selecting the control in the design window then right clicking on it and selecting bring to front, this should make it get drawn last..

Comment: That i mentioned in the Question, for the Designer and also by the code I did that (BringtoFront()). Thanks Sayse!

Comment: BringToFront() in code is different to what the designer is doing when you say bring, has this solved your question?..

Comment: In the Designer : I have right clicked and select bring to Front. When using the user control in another UC  I did like this : UCName.BringtoFront(); This is what i mean by the Designer and code!

Comment: I will explain the scenario here : On drop down of the combo i am cancelling the DropDown event by e.Cancel=true;. Then, I just increase the height of the UC. By increasing the UC height it will act like a Combo Box. Its working fine, but the UC not on top. its hiding inside the parent control. Please help me! Thank you.